# Loading obj-c files with storyboard in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am new to the Swift world, and have created a very basic app that loads up 3 views from a storyboard controller called `Main`

```
@IBAction func view2ButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: Test2ViewController.self)) as? Test2ViewController {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
    
@IBAction func view3ButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: Test3ViewController.self)) as? Test3ViewController {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

However, I have also copied over a `.h` & `.m` as well as a storyboard from an older `obj-c` project, I have setup the bridging header, and I am trying to load it using the following method;

```
@IBAction func view1ButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "CompassView", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CompassViewController")
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    
}
```

However it crashes with the error;

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'CompassView' in bundle NSBundle
```

When I locate the Compass storyboard file, I check the name and it is `Compass.storyboard`

and the custom class is `CompassViewController` and storyboard ID is `CompassView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I locate the Compass storyboard file, I check the name and it is **Compass.storyboard**

then you should load it like this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Compass", bundle: nil)
```

Comment: Sometimes it's so easy to miss the obvious! I appreciate your answer thank you!